# Why does System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher needs to be fully qualified to compile

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, namespaces

I'm learning about WCF and found [this article](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2010/06/16/wcf-simple-example-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) on a simple WCF example.

In the following code (from the above article), why does the `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher` in the foreach loop need to be fully qualified when there is a `using System.ServiceModel;`? While `ServiceHost` doesn't need to be fully qualified for it to work and it is from the same namespace as `Dispatcher`.

If you remove the `System.ServiceModel` from `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher` in the loop the code doesn't compile.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ConsoleHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type serviceType = typeof(EmailService.EmailValidator);
            Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");

            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, serviceUri);
            host.Open();

            foreach (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in host.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}, {1}", dispatcher.Listener.Uri.ToString(), dispatcher.BindingName); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ServiceHost` is a class on the System.ServiceModel namespace (which you have in the using statements); `ChannelDispatcher` is a class on the System.ServiceModel.**Dispatcher** namespace. If you add this using statement below, you'll be able to use ChannelDispatcher without being fully-qualified.

```
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
```

Comment: so because `Dispatcher` is not a class it can't have a shortcut through another namespace? I guess I misunderstood using blocks to be shortcuts for all things not just classes. That makes sense as in a lot of cases you wouldn't have to have any other `using` statement besides `using System;` Thanks.